# How can I configure the GWT Designer in the Google eclipse plugin

Tags: gwt, gwt-designer, google-eclipse-plugin

I created a GWT project and everything was great, but then I decided to change the entry point of the application.
It turns out that the class implementing **EntryPoint** has to be at top level inside the client package.

**com.company.project.myui.client.WebUI** was my original setup - I changed it to
**com.company.project.myui.client.ui.NewEntryPoint**
When I realized that this is not a supported configuration, I changed it back and everything is compiling, but now the GWT designer expects my views to be somewhere under
**com.company.project.myui.client.ui.client** which is wrong and it wont parse any of the ui classes.

I can't figure out where it is getting this configuration from.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by deleting the second bundle and its bundle.xml configuration file.
Still, in my opinion  this was unexpected behavior from the GWT designer.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide a test case and a more complete error description (a complete stack trace at minimum).

Comment: There was no exception that I could find.